# prove that if T is invertible transformation there is polynomial $p$ such that $T^{-1} = p(T) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, diagonalization

I know how to prove this using Hamilton.C but something doesn't make sense to me.

if I assume that there is such polynomial p(x), so p(T)T = I .

then looking at these polynomials I get: p(x)x = 1
so deg p(x) + deg (x) = deg (1)

and degree of polynomial is >= 0 , but deg (1) = 0 so how is it possible? what is not right with what I'm doing? thanks

Answer (score 0):

$p(T)T=I$ does *not* imply $p(x)x=1$.

The evaluation map $E: k[x] \to L(V)$ given by $E(p)=p(T)$ is *not* injective. There are non-zero polynomials that are sent to zero; $p(T)T-I$ is one of them. The characteristic polynomial is another (that's the Cayley–Hamilton theorem).

That phenomenon is common. Consider $\omega=(-1+\sqrt3)/2$. Then $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ and so $\omega(-\omega-1)=1$ and $\omega^{-1}=-\omega-1$, but $x(-x-1)=1$ does not hold as a polynomial equality.

Comment: Can you please pay attention to what I wrote? I know how to prove it but somehow I found something the contradicts it and I don't understand what is wrong with it @lhf

Comment: @user84636, see my new answer. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: thank you for your help. I learned in class that , for example, if gcd (f(x), g(x)) = 1 then there p and q such that p(x)*f(x)+q(x)*g(x) = 1 . and in order to prove some proofs the professor plugged T (linear transformation) and got : p(T)*f(T)+q(T)*g(T) = I , is it not right to do? I don't understand where it is correct.. @lhf